# Can't get Java app to listen on port for remote debugging purposes?

Tags: java, linux, debugging, spring-boot

I have a **Spring Boot Java app** running on **Ubuntu 14.x** using **Oracle Java 1.8.0** that I want to debug remotely with IntelliJ.  I have tried to get it to listen on a port for debug purposes but with no success.  Note, the ports I tried are all **well above the port 1024**, to make sure it's not a permission problem.  I am not root but I do have sudo access to the box.

I tried adding this to the java command line:

```
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=localhost:9009,server=y,suspend=y
```

A technique I got from this document:

```
http://javahowto.blogspot.com/2010/09/java-agentlibjdwp-for-attaching.html
```

However when I run this command:

```
sudo netstat -an | grep LISTEN
```

I don't see port 9009.  Also, the app does not wait for debugger attachment as indicated by the "suspend=y" parameter, because I see the app initialization messages stream by as normal as the app starts up.  Why isn't this working?

Here is the shell script that launches the app.  Note, this shell script is launched by **supervisord**.  I point this out in case that might be causing any trouble:

```
# !/bin/bash 
# Shell script to launch Spring Boot app

# Kill subprocess when parent bash process is terminated by supervisor or when CTRL+C is received
trap 'kill -TERM $PID' TERM INT


java \
  -Dnetworkaddress.cache.ttl=5 \
  -Dnetworkaddress.cache.negative.ttl=5 \
   \
  -jar spbootapp.jar \
  -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=localhost:9009,server=y,suspend=y
  --spring.application.name=spbootapp-awsdev \
  --spring.profiles.active=cluster \
  --spring.cloud.config.enabled=false \
  --endpoints.configprops.enabled=false \
  --endpoints.health.sensitive=false \
  &
```

Comment: Try `-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=9009` in place of your current debug parameters and see if that helps. EDIT: Also the parameters need to go BEFORE the `-jar`, which is most likely your problem.

Comment: @kon No need to try the older style command line.  You're suggestion about re-positioning the parameter solved it.  Please turn your comment into an answer so I can accept it.  Thanks!

Comment: Done, didn't realize that was the older style

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The debug parameters `-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=localhost:9009,server=y,suspend=y` need to go before the `-jar` in the command.

Comment: Big thank you. All portal for some reason putting this parameter in the end.

Comment: @Sergey Glad it was helpful